# Powershell - assign source code of ASP page to a variable

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, vbscript

probably it is a silly question, but I couldn't find the answer in Google so far.
I need to read the HTML source code of a page
http://Mysite/ViewRequest.aspx?request_id=xxx.
I've setup following

```
wc = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$wc.visible = $false
$wc.navigate2($strGRSpage).Document
$wc.silent = $true
$wc.visible = $false
$GRSstr = $wc.Document.body.IHTMLElement_outerText
```

Unfortunately the IE page pops up, even if I set $wc.silent = $true and $wc.visible = $false.
Is there another way (even with HTTP request GET) to retrieve that data without getting the IE page.
NOTE. The site http://Mysite/ViewRequest.aspx?request_id=xxx supports just IE and Mozilla. When I tried to use Webclient Class I get always unsupported browser.

In VBscript following works (but I want it in Powershell)

```
Set oHTML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")  
Set oWeb = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")  
oHTML.open "GET" , strGRSpage, false 
oHTML.send  
strGRStext = oHTML.responseText
```

Many thanks,

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add an appropriate `user-agent` header.

For example:

```
$wc = new-object system.net.webclient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")
$wc.DownloadFile("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/","d:\index.html")
```

Comment: I already tried to specify the User agent, but I get the same error.
Is there a way to simulate IE User agent?

Answer (score 1):

When trying the webclient Class maybe You're just missing to add a "valid" user Agent

$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Valid WebClient Header")

Answer (score 0):

After Googling a little bit I found out how to setup my user agent to get the compatibility with IE.

```
Final code is 
$wc = new-object system.net.webclient
$wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Windows-RSS-Platform/2.0 (MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)")
$GRSstr = $wc.DownloadString($strGRSpage)
```

Many thanks for your help.

Regards,
Marco

----- Please mark as answer ------